# Book suggestion on differential equations (ODE, PDE) .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, book-recommendation

I am studying differential equations. I want to know some of the best ever written texts in ODE and PDE . Which gives an intutive ideas for these subjects.
As I have studied S L ROSS . So I want to know some other classic texts to be more better in these fields.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as primary opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

> Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes by
> George F. Simmons

This book contains lot of historical notes as the title suggest and I find it very good for an introductory course.